# How to get data from database?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have created 'smphas' table in my database. To retrieve the data, I write this code:

```
function goBack() {
  window.location.replace("dashboardproject.jsp");
```

}

```
 function getQuarter(phase){
  if(phase==""){
     alert("PLEASE CHOOSE PHASE"); 
  } else {
  document.getElementById("phase").value = phase;
  constructionprogress.submit();
  }
```

}

```
  function selected(){
  $('#phaseCons').val('<%=phase%>');
```

}

Mysql command is:

```
    public List<String[]> constPeriodPhase (String projCde,String co_no){
    System.out.println("/*** constPeriodPhase ***/");

    String sql = "SELECT distinct smh_phase_num, smh_phase_nme FROM c"+co_no+".smphas WHERE smh_proj_cde = '"+projCde+"'";
    System.out.println("Execute = "+sql);
    return super.execListStrArr(sql,false); 
}
```

However, the error is:

/*** constPeriodPhase ***/
Execute = SELECT distinct smh_phase_num, smh_phase_nme FROM cnull.smphas WHERE smh_proj_cde = 'null'
nullnulle-Solicitor[cnull.smphas]
2020-03-12 09:53:58.165 SGT EXECUTE: SELECT distinct smh_phase_num, smh_phase_nme FROM cnull.smphas WHERE smh_proj_cde = 'null'
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'cnull'

How can i retrieve the database from mysql?

Answer (score -2):

`Unknown database 'cnull'`

with a query:

```
...FROM c"+co_no+".smp
```

mean co_no is null when the function was called.